# high availability apache/mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, high-availability

I have a simple task but too many software options, so I wanted someone experienced to give me a clue.

The task is:
1) In the company we have a server that runs apache and mysql on debian (it's a dedicated server). What we need is too be able to access it at any time, so the question is how to setup a 100% replication server(s) in another location(s) and to be able to switch (automatically) in case the first server fails(or looses internet connection, etc).

2) Optional it will be great thing to be able to have file system(not the database) on both (or probably more) servers to be fully functional (i.e. if the file changes on any of the servers it will propagate changes to all other servers).

I see it as three different tasks: a) the database sync(mysql has built in support for replication, will that be enough?); b) filesystem sync(DRBD or a special file system?); c) failover (several A-records in DNS?)

What would be the best software solutaion for that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Create a linux cluster with a floating vip and Pacemaker and Corosync or several DNS entries in the case you want geographic redundancy

-Determine which part of filesystem should be replicated, and rsync it

-Use MySQL Cluster to replicate data

Comment: 1) googling your suggestions. what is the difference between Mysql cluster and mysql replication? 2) also rsync is not very well scalable , i was thinking about a file system or block device mirroring or something like that. what can you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Let us goes without regarding server machine.

You need web server cluster to enhance the availability of web service providing.
And you can configure `CDN` to cache static file remotely to accelerate visiting speed and reduce server load.

As for database:

You can create a mysql cluster with I/O separation and master/slaver backup.

`mysql cluster` is focus on database server capability, to provide higher availability to process client request;
`I/O separation` is to separate  `read` and `write` action from different machine, reducing load of a single server machine's Hard Disc `searching time` and increase I/O performance;
While `replication` is focus on higher `Data availability` that even some of the hard disc is fail, data from other site can still provide the  service.

Also, you can have a `RAID` Disc cluster to enhance your data availability more.

Comment: Actually I don't think we need all of this. At the moment we don't handle that much data and the focus is not high throughput but being able to access server without interruption 100% of the time

Comment: @FyodorDostoyevsky So, you could just deploy part of what I mentioned!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, voting to close this - its **way** too broad a question for this forum. (and writing here instead of a comment as the explanation is a little verbose).

HA is about balancing availability, performance and data integrity (and sometimes functionality). There are multiple solutions for each tier all with different characteristics for each of these aspects.

As long as all your *data* is in the mysql database, then replicating the Linux, Apache and application code is relatively simple - but if you do have data in files then life becomes a lot more complicated.

However I can think of 8 methods of replicating a mysql instance off the top of my head. You've not provided nearly enough information to make a call on what might be appropriate to your situation.

I will recommend that you start by learning a lot more about HA (before engaging with someone who can provide you with better advice - but be prepaerd to pay for this) - e.g. you talk about failover without considering how to deal with split-brain.

Comment: I apologize for setting this question in such a way, but what i really need is a simple solution for 2 servers right now. As i said data is in Mysql database, not in the files, so that's not a problem. Raul Andres gave some good hints, but he advised "rsync" for file syncing which is a pain. For files I was looking for something dropbox-like. I am searching in google all day and just wanted a clue from the community to look into some specific projects.

Comment: If you consider rsync to be a pain, then you're in for a big fright when you learn a bit more about database replication.

Comment: pain in way that you it's not automatic and if it's scheduled (cron for example) then it consumes a lot of resources, etc. also it's hard to sync among several servers :) as for the database -- what is the problem if need only one server to be master at a time? the database just replicates async -- that's what i though...